# MySQL three queries: change LIMIT depending on result of previous query

Tags: mysql, sql

I can't figure out how to implement MySQL query more efficiently in this situation:

Table1

```
id | reg_id | lang_id |
---|--------|---------|
 1 |    9   |    3    |
---+--------+---------|
 2 |    7   |    8    |
---+--------+---------|
 3 |    9   |    3    |
---+--------+---------|
 4 |    1   |    1    |
---+--------+---------|
 5 |    3   |    8    |
---+--------+---------|
 6 |    7   |    22   |
---+--------+---------|
...more
```

I need to fetch 12 rows in total from the table above on three different WHERE conditions, 4 rows for each condition, for example:

```
SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE reg_id = 9 AND lang_id = 3 LIMIT 4
SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE reg_id = 3 AND lang_id = 8 LIMIT 4
SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE reg_id = 1 AND lang_id = 1 LIMIT 4
```

This is where I get confused:

All 12 rows need to be filled with data from three queries above, 4 records each.

But if the 1st query returns only 2 records, then its missing rows need to be filled with records from the 2nd query, so, in this case, the 2nd query will need to return 6 rows. But if the 2nd query has only 3 records, then its space needs to be filled with records from the 3rd query, so in this case, the 3rd query will need to return 7 rows.

So in total there have to be 12 rows filled.

I can do it with PHP statements by going back and forth to the database, counting rows and querying for the next set of data, but it does not look efficient to me, so I'm trying to figure out if the logic can be done inside a query via sub-queries or something. So single query could return the required data.

Can someone advice an idea?

Comment: Select 12 rows per every condition in one query then filter additionally in php

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET. Note also that LIMIT without ORDER BY is pretty much meaningless.